# Возврат выполнения кода к необходимой строке

Tags: java

Я только учусь и не знаю многих базовых вещей, по этому не ругайтесь сильно)
Есть код:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Введите сумму, которую необходимо внести на счёт");
    if (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
        int InputSumma = scanner.nextInt();
    } else {
        System.out.println("Вы ввели неверное значение");
    }
}
```

Вопрос вот в чём заключается, если выполняется else, есть ли оператор или что-то ещё, что могло бы перевести исполнение кода к строчке с просьбой внести деньги.

Comment: Например, можно использовать цикл `while(!scanner.hasNextInt()) {System.out.println("Вы ввели неверное значение");}` , как только будет введено число цикл закончит свое выполнение

Comment: а вообще в java есть возможность использовать метки с операторами `brake`  и `continue`, более подробно можно посмотреть здесь http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/java/break.php

Comment: @LexHobbit Точно, как вариант, спасибо

Comment: @LexHobbit у вас опечатка, `brake` это «тормоз», но по смыслу все равно подходит. :)

Comment: @Nick Volynkin хах, да, забавная опечатка =)

Comment: @LexHobbit Попробовал сегодня ваш вариант, он работает отлично, если вводить число, а если не число вводиться, то цикл бесконечно повторяет : Вы ввели неверное значение, как сделать, чтобы он 1 раз вывел сообщение и ждал ввода? Уже час голову ломаю)

Comment: @Andrew гляньте сюда (https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/scanner_nextint.htm)

Comment: @LexHobbit Нужно в цикл вставить где-то scanner.close, я верно понимаю?

Comment: @Andrew суть была не в этом. Во-первых почитайте что такое Scanner (например, (здесь)(https://metanit.com/java/tutorial/2.9.php)). В предыдущем примере по идее почти то же самое, что и у Вас, только добавлен `while`. Можете указать, что конкретно вы хотите в итоге получить...(отредактируйте и уточните вопрос) очень похоже, что вы пытаетесь организовать интерактивное консольное меню, с подпунктами и считыванием информации от пользователя.